# Trying to build a slack bot and facing error "Error: not_allowed_token_type"

Tags: javascript, node.js, slack

Was just trying to build a simple slack bot by following a YouTube link and started getting the error 
**Error: not_allowed_token_type**

```
const bot = new SlackBot({
token: 'xoxb-TOKEN_GENERATED FROM SLACK SITE',
name: 'escalatorbot'  // what name should I give here
})
```

Can somebody tell why I am facing this error

Comment: Hi Osten, does this slack service happen to be behind firewall?

Answer (score 2):

From your code snippet, I think you're using Slackbots.js and encountering a known problem resulting from recent changes in the slack api. The issue is logged here: https://github.com/mishk0/slack-bot-api/issues/145

Comment: the issue has been fixed, Thank you for helping though : )

Comment: hi @OstenDiniz - can you please share a link or the steps you took? I am facing same issue using nodejs

Answer (score 1):

The issue is releated with the new granular permissions app in slack, use the legacy bot on this url: https://api.slack.com/apps?new_classic_app=1 and then in Bots you can add legacy bot user and generate correct token

Answer (score 0):

I have not fully understood your use case. On which API you got this error? For now, I can suggest you to use slack built-in tool for testing all API's (https://api.slack.com/methods/api.test/test)

Comment: Is it related to Oauth 1.0 vs 2.0? I think 1.0 tokens are deprecated by Slack. Is it related to that?